# What is an appropriate method of storing settings that are application specific but user editable in a C# program?

Tags: c#, .net, settings

The specific situation is this:

Application Development Environment:

- PC Running a windows 8
- Visual Studio Pro 2013
- PC is not joined to a domain
- Project is being coded in C#

Target for the program:

- 2 servers running Windows Server 2012 R2
- Both are members of a domain
- Both will run the application locally for RDP connected users
- Will need to store data to an SQL 2005 server on the same domain as the 2012 servers
- Will need to retrieve csv files from a sftp server

Goals:

- store a connection string to an SQL server on the domain
- store user name and password to access an sftp server
- Have all users using one common connection string to the SQL server
- Have all users using one common set of auth credentials to the sftp server
- Allow for the changing of either the connection string or the sftp credentials
- Store the connection string and the sftp credential with encryption
- Don't deploy the application with un-encrypted credentials and then encrypt after installation
- Don't ever make either the connection string or the sftp credentials readable for the users
- Allow the stored connection string and credentials to be portable ( if possible )

Description:

I'm making an application that will retrieve a csv from an sftp server, import it, then load the parsed data into an SQL database. I need to store authentication credentials for the sftp server so I can get the data file. After that I need to import the data and then load it into some SQL tables. I'm not coding the application while joined to the domain but I still do have network access to the SQL server. While I'm building the application I need to be able to have a connection string that includes username and password. Once its done I think I can use a trusted connection instead though. I'm trying to protect all those settings as best I can. Right now though I'm not sure what system of storing them would be most appropriate. When the application gets deployed to our users I need to be able to set those credentials for the program to use and then again if they ever need to change. I don't want anyone being able to see the passwords though so I'm trying to store them encrypted and won't provide anyway to view them. I just need to be able to set them so the application has the ability to access the sftp server and the SQL server.

Comment: Your specific situation is not very clear.  What type of application are you developing?  Is it a desktop application? A web application? What connectivity settings are you talking about? Is it database connection string? Your application is used by multiple users and yet the settings are not per user.  Can the application be used by multiple users at the same time? What would be the impact if a user modified the settings while another user is using your application?

Comment: Sometimes us novices don't know how much information is needed to discern what a good solution is for our current problem. The type of app could be described as information gathering and report printing for desktop use. Its not a web application and to be honest I didn't know you could use C# for web app development. The settings I'm working on are both for database connectivity and for sftp access. Collisions weren't a concern as the settings would only be edited with specific direction.

Comment: Hello Donovan, no worries.  This is what we are for -- to help each other. The're still some inconsitencies with you question.  I think what's throwing me off is the statement that the configuration setting s (database/ftp) is user editable in the question title.  See my answer below if it's applicable to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Application Settings should be enough. Please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a65txexh.aspx

They are portable - since all settings are stored in file, they can also be set per user or per machine. About editing - since settings are plain xml file, users can just edit them with any editor or you can provide your own editor for the config with proper validation etc.

Comment: Any idea if this would be an impediment to what I'm trying to accomplish: Application-scoped settings can be used for information such as a URL for a Web service or a database connection string. These values are associated with the application. Therefore, users cannot change them at run time.

Comment: I wonder if having edit access to that type of setting at run time is just a bad idea and I didn't know enough to know that part.

Comment: The more I read on about application settings the more it looks like app.config is where Microsoft intends for these types of settings to live in that file.

Answer (score 1):

First, determine the frequency of the changes for the database and ftp settings.  This will determine how much effort you need to do to put in place a mechanism to manage these encrypted settings.

If it's low frequency, just use the standard App.config which is portable.  On this file, store the encrypted database and ftp settings.  The app will decrypt the settings before use.  When there's a need to change the settings,  on the development environment prepare a new configuration file with the updated encrypted settings and deploy the new config file to the target environment.

If the frequency is high, just do the same as above but it will be painful to constantly prepare and update the config and redeploy everytime.  So instead of doing that,  add some authentication and authorization feature on your app.  Only a user with admin rights, he or she can open a form that can read/decrypt the settings on the config, change the values, and save the encrypted settings back on the config file.

Comment: I like your consideration for the frequency of changing the settings. It will definitely be low frequency. An I think the App.config sounds like the most likely choice. As I read about that method though I have begun to wonder how I can implement it in a way that the encrypted information is usable to another server. I've read that if the settings are encrypted by one machine then its not a given they can be decrypted by another. That may throw out any idea of portability all together.